# I have a list named CB whose elements are also lists, how to keep only the unique elements of CB? np.unique() or list(set()) do not work

Tags: python, list, numpy, unique

I have a very long list named CB with possibly repeated elements. For example, CB could be `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]`. Each element in CB is a list of sorted numbers.

In this example, I want to keep
`[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [1,1], [1,2], [2,2]]`.

I've tried to use `CB1=np.unique(CB)`, but it returns `[0,1,2]`, which is not what I wanted.
I also tried to use CB1=list(set(CB)), but got the following error:  TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.

How to solve this problem? It would be great if you could solve it with the simplest possible code. A python function or one line of code would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: `list(map(list,set(map(tuple, data))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `np.unique`, you want to use the `axis` keyword argument:

```
data = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
np.unique(data, axis=0)

array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2]])
```

if you want to use `set`, you need to convert to hashable type, e.g. `tuple`:

```
data = map(tuple, data)
set(data)

{(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)}
```

if you need then converted back to the original `list` type, then the complete 1-liner would be:

```
data = list(map(list,set(map(tuple, data))))
```

Comment: Thanks, Julien! This is extremely helpful, and completely solved my problem.

Comment: Another question, after applying the np.unique(data, axis=0) command, each element in the output is of type numpy.narray. But I still want the output to be a list of lists. How to do this in one line (without using loop)?

Comment: If ending up with `np.array` type is an issue to you, then why not just using the 2nd approach I already provided?

Comment: Also note that no matter what code you write there will be a loop running under the hood...

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. I also found the .tolist() method combined with your first method works too.